# How to select the last latest records with associated IDs from the excluded row on the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a sample table below and a sql statement that I used but I need some help on some certain issue on this.
Based on the table below **I need to get only the last latest results based on MessageIDs that are associated with the UseEmail
of the excluded row**. By using the statement sql below, it will give all the results of one set of records associated with the
MessageID but **all I need is the latest results based on MessageID ordered by Id in Desc order**. For further explanations, look through all the details below. Thanks!

Sql Statement used so far,

```
select  Id,UserEmail,SellerEmail,Messages,UserName,MessageID 
from [MessagesTab] 
where MessageID in
( 
    select  MessageID 
    from [MessagesTab]
    where UserEmail = @useremail
) 
and UserEmail <> @useremail  Order by Id Desc;
```

**Table**

```
 Id      UserEmail                SellerEmail         Messages             UserName       MessageID
 19     ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com    KTV21@outlook.com   Hi!...               Katie          13d6c0c9
 20     KTV21@outlook.com         KTV21@outlook.com   Hello.               Seller's Name  13d6c0c9  
 21     ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com    KTV21@outlook.com   Where are you?       Katie          13d6c0c9  
22     dsffhfg56@gmail.com        KTV21@outlook.com   When will you call?  Jenny          69e37491  
23     KTV21@outlook.com          KTV21@outlook.com   I'll meet you there. Seller's Name  13d6c0c9  
24     KTV21@outlook.com          KTV21@outlook.com    Ok. Let's go.        Seller's Name  69e37491
```

**@useremail = ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com** - It will give a result of

```
23     KTV21@outlook.com    KTV21@outlook.com      I'll meet you there.    Seller's Name      13d6c0c9
20     KTV21@outlook.com    KTV21@outlook.com      Hello.                  Seller's Name      13d6c0c9
```

but I only need the last latest results based on **MessageID** which is ordered by **Id** in **desc** order like this below

```
23     KTV21@outlook.com    KTV21@outlook.com      I'll meet you there.    Seller's Name      13d6c0c9
```

same as **@useremail =  KTV21@outlook.com** - It will give a result of

```
22      dsffhfg56@gmail.com     KTV21@outlook.com     When will you call?   Jenny       69e37491
21      ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com  KTV21@outlook.com     Where are you?        Katie       13d6c0c9
19      ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com  KTV21@outlook.com     Hi!...                Katie       13d6c0c9
```

but I only need the last latest results based on **MessageID** which is ordered by **Id** in **desc** order like this below

```
22         dsffhfg56@gmail.com   KTV21@outlook.com   When will you call?    Jenny       69e37491
21      ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com   KTV21@outlook.com   Where are you?         Katie       13d6c0c9
```

Comment: use a row_number() over (partition by useremail  order by  id desc in your query

Comment: @anwaar_hell Which exactly should I insert that additional statement in part of my query that I provided above?

Comment: Also can you write expected output to create query...

Comment: @Timmack...is your problem solved..?

Comment: Yes, buddy... Thanks, I almost forgot to thank you. Cheers!

Comment: @timmack..glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select * from (
select  Id,UserEmail,SellerEmail,Messages,UserName,MessageID ,
row_number () over (partition by UserEmail order by ID desc  ) as rnm
from [MessagesTab] 
where MessageID in
( 
    select  MessageID 
    from [MessagesTab]
    where UserEmail = 'ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com'
) 
and UserEmail <> 'ddfgdfjn84@outlook.com' ) x
where rnm =1;
```

Comment: SQLSyntax46010:Incorrect syntax near where. What is the syntax error in here?

Comment: from your query what i understood that you want those records where SellerEmail is not equal to useremail ..right?

Comment: No, as for the result. The UserEmail and SellerEmail could have an equal value as what I described above as one of the result I need.

Comment: I encountered a syntax error near where clause from your answer above. Can you trace the error?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MessageID ORDER BY ID DESC)` will do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    Id, UserEmail, SellerEmail, Messages, MessageID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MessageID ORDER BY ID DESC)
    FROM MessagesTab
    WHERE 
        UserEmail <> @useremail
        AND MessageID IN(
            SELECT MessageID
            FROM MessagesTab
            WHERE UserEmail = @useremail
        )
) t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: @Felix..do we need to do order by again when we are already generating row_number by ordering ID in descending order.

Comment: It's up to the OP. However, the `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER` does not guarantee the order of the whole `SELECT` query.